# How to integrate my wordpress blog in my subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, integration, root

I am trying to integrate my wordpress blog, which I use for news and updates to my website, in a different subdomain. The code I am using on my main page is the following:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<!-- blog post -->
         <?php

$number_of_posts = 5;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $number_of_posts );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){
echo "<div class='post_title'>".$recent_post['post_date']."</div><br>";
echo "<h3>".$recent_post['post_title']."</h3>";
echo "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><center><img src='line.jpg'></center>";
}

?>
```

Here's the result:[image]

Whenever I try to do the same on my subdomain the index page breaks and I get a 500 error.

I've tried changing `require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');` to `require('https://retro-media.net/blog/wp-blog-header.php')` but that doesn't work.

I know it would be easier to just have a new wordpress installation on my subdomain but I would like to use the same blog and make it global while only showing specific categories on specific subdomains.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do such thing. You need to either use a network site to achieve what you're looking for. Otherwise you use rest api to get those posts of yours & do necessary things like make a shortcode of yours.

You can get your posts in a json format if you visit https://retro-media.net/wp/v2/posts & it'll generate the json format of your posts. Fetch that & do whatevery you want. For more information check [wp-codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/)